# is there way to rename default linux directories (dev, sbin, root, etc.)

Tags: linux

Ok, strange question. I want to rename (move and rename, to be more precise) default Linux directories such as dev or sbin (e.g., to /system/devices and /administration/binary). I tried to find some settings in menuconfig of kernel's compilation, but, at the first sight, the kernel does not have options for this. Is it possible without symlinking and other dishonest ways?

Comment: The kernel is not concerned with the folder structure. It is entirely up to the userland.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. From our [help pages](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask): "You should only ask *practical* […] questions based on *actual problems* that you face". What is the practical significance of such remapping? Modified Linux will work equally well, assuming the remapping is flawless. It may not be. It seems you can only make things worse or equally fine in the best case. Even if you build such OS once, you will confuse users who know anything about Linux; and scripts/tools you may want to use in the future. What is a single advantage? an actual problem you want to solve?

Comment: Even if you do manage to rename them - there is no guarantee that the OS and installed packages will work. Many packages depend on certain standard system directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, yes and no.

The Linux kernel actually doesn't care about most of them, aside from just a few paths (such as direct firmware loading from `/lib/modules/*/firmware`, or upcalls such as `/sbin/request-key`). Everything else is exclusively used just by userspace tools. The `/sbin/init` path is only special to the kernel if you do not have an initramfs – if you do, then it's the initramfs that decides what to execute as init.

So as far as the *kernel* goes, you can rename almost everything freely, and just patch a few remaining hardcoded paths if necessary.

However, *every other package* cares about these paths. Various programs will have standard paths compiled in – for example, just like most scripts have a fixed interpreter path like `#!/bin/sh` declared at the top, so does every ELF binary executable reference the path `/lib/ld-linux.so.2` as the "ELF interpreter" (statically-linked executables being the exception).

At compile time, many programs also look up specific paths via pkg-config and embed them in the program itself or its data files. For example, most daemons expect their configuration files to be specifically in `/etc` or `/etc/theprogram`, etc.

So while this is technically possible, it's a lot of work – approximately like starting your own distro completely from scratch – and most likely you will *still* need to keep symlinks like `/bin -> /Programs` for compatibility. Actually, some distributions like [Gobo Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GoboLinux) *have* tried exactly this, and they have to keep symlinks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you symlink, you may get away with it, if you move them, no, the dev directory at least is all hardcoded in so many files. Some of /sbin *may* be hardcoded in scripts and exe's. While you may get some errors popping up after you do it, it will be nothing compared to when you reboot.